# Finding solution to maze in java

Tags: java, awt, path-finding, maze

I have a project to have a red dot inside the first box of a maze i randomly generated and the dot is supposed to follow its way through the boxes and find the end of the maze. Now if it hits a dead end, its supposed to go back to where its path started and not go back down that path, that leads to a dead end. i made it so each box represents the #1, this way when the red dot travels over the box, it increments by 1, so it can realize where its been. its always supposed to go to the lowest number possible so it can never go back to the dead ends its already been to. i am able to reach the end of the maze but i come into 2 problems.

the method i wrote that does all this work is the solve() function. I cant understand why 2 things happen...
1st thing is that when the red dot comes to a branch of dead ends, sometimes itll just go to one dead end, to a different dead end , back to the same dead end.. traveling to the same 'numbers' when im trying to have it only go towards the boxes that have 1's or just the lower numbers. 
2nd thing is that once it inevitably reaches the end of the maze.. the red dot goes into the green area, where i specifically say in the while loop, it can not be in a green box.

if M[y][x] = 0, its a green box and if its = 1 its a black box. anything higher than 1 will also be inside the box.

your help is highly appreciated as ive been stuck on this problem for hours and cant seem to find out the problem.

the problem persists in the solve() method

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mazedfs extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
/* default values: */
private static int bh = 16;     // height of a graphical block
private static int bw = 16;    // width of a graphical block
private int mh = 41;    // height and width of maze
private int mw = 51;
private int ah, aw;    // height and width of graphical maze
private int yoff = 40;    // init y-cord of maze
private Graphics g;
private int dtime = 40;   // 40 ms delay time
byte[][] M;    // the array for the maze
public static final int SOUTH = 0;
public static final int EAST = 1;
public static final int NORTH = 2;
public static final int WEST = 3;

public static boolean showvalue = true; // affects drawblock

// args determine block size, maze height, and maze width
public mazedfs(int bh0, int mh0, int mw0)
 { 
   bh = bw = bh0;  mh = mh0;  mw = mw0;
   ah = bh*mh;
   aw = bw*mw;
   M = new byte[mh][mw];  // initialize maze (all  0's - walls).
   this.setBounds(0,0,aw+10,10+ah+yoff);    
   this.setVisible(true);
   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   try{Thread.sleep(500);} catch(Exception e) {} // Synch with system
   this.addKeyListener(this);  
   g = getGraphics();    //g.setColor(Color.red);
   setup();
 }

public void paint(Graphics g) {} // override automatic repaint

public void setup()
   { 
     g.setColor(Color.green);
     g.fill3DRect(0,yoff,aw,ah,true);  // fill raised rectangle
     g.setColor(Color.black);
     //     showStatus("Generating maze...");
     digout(mh-2,mw-2); // start digging!
     // digout exit
     M[mh-1][mw-2] = M[mh-2][mw-1] = 1;
     drawblock(mh-2,mw-1);
     solve();  // this is the function you will write for parts 1 and 2
     play();   // for part 3
   }   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       int blocksize = bh, mheight = 41, mwidth = 41; // need to be odd
       if (args.length==3)
       {
           mheight=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
           mwidth=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           blocksize=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
       }
       mazedfs W = new mazedfs(blocksize,mheight,mwidth);
    }

public void drawblock(int y, int x)
    {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(x*bw,yoff+(y*bh),bw,bh);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    // following line displays value of M[y][x] in the graphical maze:
    if (showvalue)
      g.drawString(""+M[y][x],(x*bw)+(bw/2-4),yoff+(y*bh)+(bh/2+6));
    }

    void drawdot(int y, int x)
    {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x*bw,yoff+(y*bh),bw,bh);               
        try{Thread.sleep(dtime);} catch(Exception e) {} 
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* function to generate random maze */
public void digout(int y, int x)
 {
     M[y][x] = 1;  // digout maze at coordinate y,x
     drawblock(y,x);  // change graphical display to reflect space dug out


     int dir = (int)(Math.random()*4);

     for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
     int [] DX = {0,0,2,-2};
     int [] DY = {-2,2,0,0};
     int newx = x + DX[dir];
     int newy = y + DY[dir];
     if(newx>=0 && newx<mw && newy>=0 && newy<mh && M[newy][newx]==0)
         {
         M[y+DY[dir]/2][x+DX[dir]/2] = 1;
         drawblock(y+DY[dir]/2,x+DX[dir]/2);
         digout(newy,newx);
         }
     dir = (dir + 1)%4;}
 } // digout


  public  void solve()  // This is the method i need help with. 
  {
    int x=1, y=1;
    drawdot(y,x);
    while(y!=mh-1 || x!=mw-1 && M[y][x]!=0){
          int min = 0x7fffffff;
          int  DX = 0;
          int  DY = 0;
        if (y-1>0 && min>M[y-1][x] && M[y-1][x]!=0){
            min = M[y-1][x];
            DX = 0;
            DY = -1;
        }//ifNORTH
        if (y+1>0 && min>M[y+1][x] && M[y+1][x]!=0){
            min = M[y+1][x];
            DY = 1;
            DX = 0;
        }//ifSOUTH
        if (x-1>0 && min>M[y][x-1] && M[y][x-1]!=0){
            min = M[y][x-1];
            DX = -1;
            DY = 0;
        }//ifWEST
        if (x+1>0 && min>M[y][x+1] && M[y][x+1]!=0){
            min = M[y][x+1];
          DX = 1;
          DY = 0;
        }//ifEAST

        M[y][x]++;
        drawblock(y,x); 
        x = x+DX;
        y = y+DY;
        drawdot(y,x); 
    }//while


      // modify this function to move the dot to the end of the maze.  That
      // is, when the dot reaches y==mh-2, x==mw-2
  } // solve


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// For part three (save a copy of part 2 version first!), you
    // need to implement the KeyListener interface.

    public void play() // for part 3
    {
    // code to setup game
    }
    // for part 3 you may also define some other instance vars outside of
    // the play function.

   // for KeyListener interface
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) // change this one
    {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();       // code for key pressed      
    System.out.println("YOU JUST PRESSED KEY "+key);
    }

} // mazedfs


////////////
// define additional classes (stack) you may need here.
```

Comment: You might need to represent each box that leads to the end of the maze with #1. And represent each box that leads to the dead ends with #4 or #5. The moment you realize that you have a dead end, start representing each box with #4 or #5 while back tracking, until you find an alternative way or a split on your left column or right column depending on your direction. Once you find it, stop representing the boxes with #4 or #5.

Comment: the maze is randomly generated, i will never know which way leads to a dead end and which way is the correct route.

Comment: The moment you hit a dead end, you are suppose to back track. This is when you should represent a dead end that you have already visited with #4 or #5 until you get to a split, then you stop representing boxes with #4 or #5.

Comment: im not sure why this worked but once i changed my if statements, checking the direction that had the smallest number, when i made sure that y-1 > 0, it had to be >=, as well as the y+1,x-1 and x+1 directions. and now it goes to the dead end and never returns to it which is what i needed, problem i have now is that i still get the red dot in the green box at the end

Answer (score 0):

The issue causing the second problem you are facing (dot moving to green box) lies in the while loop condition`y!=mh-1 || x!=mw-1 && M[y][x]!=0` . The condition evaluates to `y!=mh-1 ||(x!=mw-1 && M[y][x]!=0)` since `&&` has higher precedence over the `||` and `||` just needs one of its operand to be true. In your case, `y!=mh-1` is still ture at the end of maze. Hence the loop continues and the dot moves into green area. To fix the issue modify the condition as `(y!=mh-1 || x!=mw-1) && M[y][x]!=0`. Hope this helps.

Comment: i had to change it to 
y!=mh-2 || x!=mw-2 && M[y][x]!=0